# svg bar chart wont display when added using setAttribute

Tags: javascript, html, svg, rect, setattribute

Ok so I created a bar chart using HTML that looked like this

```
   <svg width="500" height="300">
       <rect y="220" height="80" width="95" transform="translate(0,0)" ></rect>
       <rect y="200" height="100" width="95" transform="translate(100,0)" ></rect>
       <rect y="244" height="56" width="95" transform="translate(200,0)" ></rect>
       <rect y="180" height="120" width="95" transform="translate(300,0)" ></rect>
       <rect y="120" height="180" width="95" transform="translate(400,0)" ></rect>
   </svg>
```

The above code made a bar chart that looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DX7i.png)

But I wanted to make it dynamic using JavaScript. So I wrote the following script.

```
var dataset = [80, 100, 56, 72, 85];

var svgWidth = 500, svgHeight = 300, barPadding = 5;
var barWidth = (svgWidth / dataset.length);

var svg = document.getElementById('bar-js');
svg.setAttribute("width", svgWidth);
svg.setAttribute("height", svgHeight);


for(var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++){
    var rect = document.createElement('RECT');
    rect.setAttribute("y", svgHeight - dataset[i])
    rect.setAttribute("height", dataset[i])
    rect.setAttribute("width", barWidth-barPadding)
    var translate = [barWidth * i, 0]
    rect.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+ translate +")")
    svg.appendChild(rect)
}
```

but for some reason that I cannot explain, even though it injects the correct HTML, nothing shows up.

it is creating HTML that looks like this

```
<svg width="500" height="300">
       <rect y="220" height="80" width="95" transform="translate(0,0)" ></rect>
       <rect y="200" height="100" width="95" transform="translate(100,0)" ></rect>
       <rect y="244" height="56" width="95" transform="translate(200,0)" ></rect>
       <rect y="228" height="72" width="95" transform="translate(300,0)" ></rect>
       <rect y="215" height="85" width="95" transform="translate(400,0)" ></rect>
   </svg>
```

So it is not an issue with getting the code to actually go into the HTML, but simply that the rectangles are not displaying despite being in the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug `rect`, you will see that the browser creates it as a `HTMLUnknownElement` object. This is because SVG elements aren't HTML. Try this:

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
```